# Propagate constructor signature to factory method

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

I'm trying to determine a method of creating a factory function generically such that I can pass a class to it and receive back a function that will create instances of that class. Something similar to:

```
function createClassFactory<T> (MyClass: {new(...):T}) {
    return function classFactory(...) {
        return new MyClass(...)
    }
}
```

In order to maintain type information I would like `classFactory` to have the same signature as the `MyClass` constructor. Right now I'm drawing a blank on how that might be possible.

Is this type of thing possible any other way?

Comment: if this [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) for variadic kinds is implemented i'll be able to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do what you want (at least not elegantly), unless you are willing to accept all constructor parameters as a single object.
If all classes expect a single object as params then you can force an interface on those props objects and using generics you can achieve what you're looking for (well, almost):

```
class Base<T> {
    constructor(props: T) {}
}

type BaseConstructor<C extends Base<P>, P> = {
    new(props: P): C; 
}

interface AProps {}

class A extends Base<AProps> {}

interface BProps {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

class B extends Base<BProps> {}

interface CProps {
    str: string;
    ok?: boolean;
}

class C extends Base<CProps> {}

function createClassFactory<C extends Base<P>, P> (MyClass: BaseConstructor<C, P>) {
    return function classFactory(props: P) {
        return new MyClass(props);
    }
}

// the following are valid:
let a1 = createClassFactory(A)({});
let b1 = createClassFactory(B)({ x: 3, y: 5 });
let c1 = createClassFactory(C)({ str: "stirng" });
let c2 = createClassFactory(C)({ str: "stirng", ok: true });

// these aren't:
let b2 = createClassFactory(B)({ x: 3, y: "5" });
let c3 = createClassFactory(C)({ ok: true });

// but this one is:
let a2 = createClassFactory(A)({ key: "value" });
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(props%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BaseConstructor%3CC%20extends%20Base%3CP%3E%2C%20P%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new(props%3A%20P)%3A%20C%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AProps%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20Base%3C%7B%7D%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20BProps%20%7B%0D%0A%09x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20Base%3CBProps%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20CProps%20%7B%0D%0A%09str%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09ok%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20Base%3CCProps%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createClassFactory%3CC%20extends%20Base%3CP%3E%2C%20P%3E%20(MyClass%3A%20BaseConstructor%3CC%2C%20P%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20classFactory(props%3A%20P)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20MyClass(props)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20the%20following%20are%20valid%3A%0D%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20createClassFactory(A)(%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20b1%20%3D%20createClassFactory(B)(%7B%20x%3A%203%2C%20y%3A%205%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20c1%20%3D%20createClassFactory(C)(%7B%20str%3A%20%22stirng%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20c2%20%3D%20createClassFactory(C)(%7B%20str%3A%20%22stirng%22%2C%20ok%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20these%20aren't%3A%0D%0Alet%20b2%20%3D%20createClassFactory(B)(%7B%20x%3A%203%2C%20y%3A%20%225%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Alet%20c3%20%3D%20createClassFactory(C)(%7B%20ok%3A%20true%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20this%20one%20is%3A%0D%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20createClassFactory(A)(%7B%20key%3A%20%22value%22%20%7D)%3B))

I say almost because of the last example where `a2` is created with a non-empty object.
But other than that I think it's pretty much what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! :) -- I was hoping to avoid that though :/